# chrome extension - popup via chrome.contextMenus.create not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

I have a Chrome Context Menu extension. I would like the user to remain on the same tab, so am trying to open a popup using chrome.contextMenus.create rather than window.open

I have used code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742449/popup-window-at-chrome-extensions-context-menu), my actual code being:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "myTitle",
    "contexts": ["page", "selection", "link", "editable"],
    "onclick": function () {
        popup(myURL + myParams);
    }
});
```

but the popup does not happen. If I use window.open then it works.

Permissions in my manifest are as follows:

```
"permissions": [
"contextMenus",
"tabs",
"http://*/*",
"https://*/*"
```

],

Any suggestions appreciated - I'd really like a popup rather than a new tab/window.

Comment: There's no such built-in `popup` function. If you want to open the extension's toolbar icon popup then it's not possible programmatically.

Comment: sorry, you're correct. i've misunderstood the original post/question. i understand what i need to do now.

Comment: You might want to inject a html-dialog into the page as an `absolute`-ly positioned `div` or `iframe`.

Comment: yes, i think that would be better, because i'd really like for everything to happen within the original page. how would i do that?

Comment: Some/many examples: [chrome extension insert|inject jquery dialog](https://www.google.com/#q=chrome+extension+insert%7Cinject+jquery+dialog).

Comment: as far as i can tell not one of those actually work?

Comment: Why? Some hits lead to questions but those have answers. For example: [Chrome Extension: Opening Jquery Ui Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12616607) (just add the required `"permissions"`). Anyway the point is that you can see the method.